# Differential equation involving history integral

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have not found a solution by using google so I hope I can ask this here.
I have an issue with a problem I am trying to solve and I was wondering whether what I am doing is not possible with mathematica's built-in tools or whether I am simply not telling mathematica the right thing ...
Minimal Working Example of my problem would be:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == Integrate[x[t - q], {q, 1, 10}],   x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 20}]
```

And the error code I get upon execution is:

```
NDSolve::rdelay: "Delay -1.\ q is not real valued."
```

I would greatly appreciate any help :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Mathematica* does not yet support delay integro-differential equations. Try to reformulate as a DDE.

Comment: This is a pity, but thank you a lot for your answer. I will look into how to reformulate these kind of problems into DDEs ...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integro-differential equation can be rewritten as

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Integrate[x[q], {q, t - 10, t - 1}], x[t /; t <= 0] == 1},
    x, {t, 0, 20}]
```

In itself, this transformation does not help.  But, it does suggest a course of action.  First, note that `x'[0] == 9`.  Then note that the DDE can be differentiated to give

```
s = NDSolve[{x''[t] == x[t - 1] - x[t - 10], x[t /; t <= 0] == 1, x'[0] == 9}, 
    x, {t, 0, 20}][[1, 1]];
```

which Mathematica can handle.

```
Plot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

We see that the slope is `9` for `0 < t < 1`, as it should be, and then `x[t]` begins to grow rapidly, again as expected.  The plot for the entire range is

```
LogPlot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Not surprisingly, growth soon becomes exponential.

**Addendum: Asymptotic Solution**

Because the second plot looks like an exponential at large `t`, it may be fruitful to compute the growth rate.  Suppose `x[t] -> c Exp[a t]` for large `t`.  Then, in this limit the left side of the DDE in the first line of code in this answer is `a x[t]`, and the right side is `Exp[-a] (1 - Exp[-9 a])/a x[t]`.  Equating the two and solving gives

```
FindRoot[a == Exp[-a] (1 - Exp[-9 a])/a, {a, .7}]
(* {a -> 0.703002} *)
```

Hence, we would expect the growth of `x[t]` for `5 < t < 20` to be approximately

```
Exp[15 a /. %]
(* 37988.2 *)
```

The actual value from `NDSolve` is

```
(x[20]/x[5]) /. s
(* 37854. *)
```

showing that `c Exp[a t]` approximates `x[t]` well even at fairly modest values of `t`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this was very instructive :)

Comment: It's a DDE and not an ODE, but it's merely a minor blemish in an otherwise nice answer.

Comment: @J.M.  Indeed, so.  I have corrected the terminology.  Thanks.

Comment: I have spent a bit of time reformulating my original problem and I have arrived at an expression like Integrate[x[q]*f[t-q], {q, 0, t}] where f[t-q] has an exponential form. I fear the same scheme as in this simple case can't successfully be applied there, can it?

Comment: @Sanya  My answer probably works only for some cases of `f[t -q]`, including that in your question above.  However, `Integrate[x[q]*f[t-q], {q, 0, t}]` is a convolution, so it should be solvable in general by means of a Laplace transform.  This is so different from what you asked above that I recommend that you ask a new question, rather than modifying the one above.  At the risk of seeming self-serving, I would ask that you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/282751) I posted, if it adequately addresses your original question.  Best wishes.

Comment: I am really sorry that I had forgotten to tick the box, this is now done :) Apart from that, I was mainly aiming at the reason for the error message with my question - thus the problem was oversimplified and I'm sorry for that; the original numerical problem is a bit more complicated and I fear it is just beyond the reach of mathematica's standard tools. I will however consider whether an integral transform of the whole system could be worth it ... Thank you again and best wishes too